# sharepoint 2010 create list from template

Tags: c#, list, templates, sharepoint, ms-word

I created a list of documents (Word) and saved it as template.
Then I created a new list from this template in code c#, and add meta data, also in code c#.

something like this:

```
SPListTemplateCollection listTemplates = web.Site.GetCustomListTemplates(web);
SPListTemplate template = listTemplates[Convert.ToString(templateName)];
Guid g = web.Lists.Add(listName.Trim(), string.Empty, template);
```

now, when i choose "New Document" option in the new list, word document is open, with the meta data i created in the list. 
this works fine when office is 2010 version. 
in 2007 version i get message that word cant save the document.

in short, i think sharepoint 2010 can not save a documnent with metadata in office 2007 into list that based on a template and created in c# code.

Answer (score 0):

I know that you can't use SharePoint 2010 Managed Metadata with Office 2007 out of the box. You can read detail information from;

[Managed meatadata columns in Office 2007](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/articles/Pages/Managed-Metadata-Columns-in-Office-2007.aspx)